# OS X 10.11 El Capitan Preview's print preview different from print result

Tags: pdf, preview, printing, macos

I've noticed something strange with printing PDFs via Preview on OS X 10.11 El Capitan. I've been printing PDF slides at 6 slides a page and they have always turned out like Figure 1.

After the upgrade to OSX 10.11, with the **exact same print settings**, they turn out like Figure 2 instead. I am printing with OSX's Preview, and the odd thing in OSX 10.11 is that the **actual printout** (Figure 2) looks entirely different from the **print preview**. (Figure 1)

I have tried printing my PDF on another machine running on 10.10.5 with the same set of print settings and it turned out like Figure 1, leading me to believe that 10.11 changed something.

It is too early to tell if it's really 10.11's fault, so I would like to see if anyone has encountered this rather odd and obscure bug.

Below are the attached print previews (it's a little small but I've labelled the slides with their slide numbers)

[image: How the print preview in OSX 10.11 looks like, and how it is printed in OSX 10.10]
*Figure 1. How the print preview in OSX 10.10 and 10.11 looks like, and how it is actually printed in OSX 10.10*

[image: How printing in OSX 10.11 turned out INSTEAD]
*Figure 2. How **the actual printout** in OSX 10.11 turned out instead (this is a photoshopped image of the actual printout because I didn't have a scanner to scan my picture in. But be rest assured this is how it looks like in real life)*

Comment: While you wait for an answer or two, please can you provide [Apple with feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) as this feels like a notable bug.

Comment: Do you see the same unexpected change in layout when printing to a PDF file on OS X 10.11?

Comment: @GrahamMiln I only see the change in layout when I print a PDF on OSX 10.11 i.e. print result different from print preview. Previously on 10.10, the print result was the same as the print preview.

Comment: Does a physically printed copy match the saved PDF or the print sheet preview? Thank you for putting up with these clarifications – it is helpful to test the various printing paths.

Comment: @GrahamMiln the physically printed copy matches Figure 2 exactly (I didn't scan it in but manipulated things in Photoshop since that's faster). Figure 1 is the print preview that I got (not Photoshopped except for adding the numbering). So no, the problem is that the physically printed copy DOES NOT MATCH the print preview at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only way to go about doing things, but I have solved this problem by **resetting my printers**, and then **adding them back**.

I suspect deleting the printer and adding that specific printer back should solve the problem as well, but this has yet to be tested, so don't take my word for it.